VS Code is asking me to choose a build command every time
I just updated VS Code to 1.89.0 and now whenever I choose Terminal > "Run Build Task..." it prompts me with all the choices below:

Previously, whenever I would choose that menu option, it would automatically just run the dotnet: build task. I don't use Java and go in any projects, so it's unclear why these are showing up, let alone every single time I try to build my dotnet project.

If you choose "Configure Default Build Task..." from the Terminal menu, you can set your default build task and the next time you "Run Build Task..." it will use that by default:

